# Different prefix, same controller/template

Tags: cakephp, url-routing, prefix, cakephp-3.x

I use cakephp 3, I have a plugin that could be used with/without prefix or different prefix.
I need to use prefix because in some case I check user login.
How I must do the route to use same controller/template?
ES:

```
/admin/media/medias/upload
/member/media/medias/upload
/media/medias/upload
```

that use /plugins/Media/src/Controller/MediasController.php

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Can You try something like this:

```
Router::plugin('Media', function ($routes) {
    $routes->prefix('admin', function ($routes) {
        $routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Medias']);
    });

    $routes->prefix('member', function ($routes) {
        $routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Medias']);
    });

    $routes->prefix('upload', function ($routes) {
        $routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Medias']);
    });
});
```